# JUnit unable to find my class

Tags: java, command-line, junit

When I run JUnit, I am receiving an error message stating that it is unable to find the test I am passing it.  However, because that class is in my working directory, and my working directory is in my class path, I'm not sure why.  Can anyone please point me in the right direction?

```
grader $  echo $JUNITPATH
/users5/cse/dfischer/lib/junit.jar:/users5/cse/dfischer/lib/hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:.
grader $  ls -l TestCalculatorWithMethod.class 
-rw-r--r-- 1 dfischer cseugrad 1625 Mar  2 20:11 TestCalculatorWithMethod.class
grader $  java -cp $JUNITPATH org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestCalculatorWithMethod.class
JUnit version 4.12
.E
Time: 0.001
There was 1 failure:
1) initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [TestCalculatorWithMethod.class]
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:102)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseArgs(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:50)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parse(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:44)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.runMain(JUnitCore.java:72)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.main(JUnitCore.java:36)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: TestCalculatorWithMethod.class
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:274)
    at org.junit.internal.Classes.getClass(Classes.java:16)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:100)
    ... 4 more

FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1
```

Comment: Tried `java -cp $JUNITPATH org.junit.runner.JUnitCore TestCalculatorWithMethod` without the `.class` at the end?

Answer (score 2):

> Tried java -cp $JUNITPATH org.junit.runner.JUnitCore
>   TestCalculatorWithMethod without the .class at the end? –  David
>   Wallace

The issue was passing in TestCalculatorWithMethod.class rather than TestCalculatorWithMethod.